# Auto Fill With Click Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, click

I want to make a simple and basic code for Google extension of auto login and click in idbi net banking. I have created 2 files like the below,

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"Auto Click",
"description":"Auto Click",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version":2,
"short_name": "Auto Click",
"content_scripts": [ { "js": [ "data.js"],
"matches": [ "https://inet.idbibank.co.in/*" ]
   } ]}
```

**data.js**

```
function login(detail){
$("input[name='CorporateSignonCorpId']").val(detail['csci']);
$("input[name='CorporateSignonPassword']").val(detail['csp']);
$("input[name='Action.ShoppingMall.Signon']").click();
}
```

They are not working in Google Chrome extension. Please help me learn how to make it work in simple code because I am a beginner in coding.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling the login function? Also check if all the data that you're trying to access is not on page window.